# Linux: substituting lines in files without need to escape 

Tags: linux

Usually when I need to replace some lines in a file, the first tool that comes to mind is `sed -i`:

```
sed -i 's|tool:.*|tool: some-tool|'
```

However, it's inconvenient when there are `.` characters in the replacement string:

```
sed -i 's|host:.*|host: 127\.0\.0\.1|'
```

Is there a better tool for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` doesn't need to be escaped in the replacement, only in the regular expression.